# Script to identify all fragmented indexes for every database on an entire server?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

am new to databases and was looking for a way to find all fragmented indexes on a server, instead of having to go through each database separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to build the command in a loop:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += '
UNION ALL 
SELECT db = ''' + name + ''', * 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(' + RTRIM(database_id)
  + ', NULL, NULL, NULL, ''SAMPLED'') -- WHERE ...'
FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4;

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql,1,14,'');

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

But then what are you doing with the output? There are better solutions out there to automate this for you. For example, [Ola Hallengren's free maintenance solution](http://ola.hallengren.com/), [Michelle Ufford (SQLFool)'s free defrag script](http://sqlfool.com/2011/06/index-defrag-script-v4-1/), and our new [SQL Sentry Fragmentation Manager](http://sqlsentry.net/fragmentation-manager/sql-server-index-analysis-and-defrag.asp).

*Disclaimer: I work for SQL Sentry.*

Comment: The output will be used to then either rebuild or reorganize the indexes based on set parameters.